# A lot of Nice Questions

Tags: support, questions, voting

About half an hour ago, exactly 41 [Nice Question badges](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/46/nice-question) were awarded almost simultaneously. I received 4 for questions which previously had 9 votes. So either someone is going around being nice, or there is a bug.

[image: long list of recently awarded nice question badges]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [msh210](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/792/a-lot-of-nice-questions/793#793) has said, it was primarily a single user that voted for questions with a score of nine.

However, the pattern doesn't look malicious and said user could have read the questions (mostly) in the award timeframe.

Hopefully, the badges will spur their recipients onward to more "Nice Questions" :)

Answer (score 4):

I have no reason to think it's not someone looking for questions with nine votes and upvoting them, but only someone with access to the database can know for (more) certain whether there's a bug here, so I suppose we'll have to await such a person (a SE employee) to come along and reply to this. Meanwhile, [no harm, no foul](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no_harm,_no_foul).

Comment: There's a party in chat now on this topic.

Comment: For future reference, that starts at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=3378655#3378655.